# nginx + gzip_static_module

Tags: nginx, gzip

**Scenario:** I have two files "style.css" and "style.css.gz". Enabled modules gzip_static and gzip. Everything works properly, NGINX serve compressed "style.css.gz". Both files have the same timestamp. I also have a cronjob that creates pre-compressed files of any file * .css and runs every two hours.

```
    gzip on;
    gunzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_static always;        
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_buffers 32 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_types                
            text/cache-manifest
            text/xml
            text/css
            text/plain
            ...........
```

**Question:** If i edit the "style.css" and change a few CSS rules, is possible to serve edited "style.css" instead of "style.css.gz"? (Based on timestamp or smthing like that) Or pre-compress new "style.css.gz" immediately after i finish editing "style.css"?
It is possible to operate using NGINX? Or what is the best solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I also have a cronjob that creates pre-compressed files of any file * .css and runs every two hours.

You can just run this script manually after you have made any edit/changes to the css file.

> It is possible to operate using NGINX? Or what is the best solution?

Alternatively, another solution I can think of (which is how I roll) is that nginx can actually serve and gzip compress files on the fly. Just make sure to disable use of precompressed files with *[ngx_http_gzip_static_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html)* otherwise nginx will use the precompressed files instead.

```
gzip_static off;
```

> Enables (“on”) or disables (“off”) checking the existence of precompressed files.